# Some PHP (Zend Framework/Doctrine) fails after reinstalling PHP (on Windows/Apache)

Tags: php, apache

i am on windows/apache/mysql/php setup. i have recently reinstalled PHP. but i found that it broke certian things. simple scripts like just `phpinfo()`, `echo`, simple OO class definitions etc works. but my Zend Framework app failed. same as the doctrine 2 sandbox i am working on. they both returned the ... below ... screen

[image]

i also noticed that if i accessed the zend framework app without `vhost` (`http://localhost/php/learningzf/public` vs `http://learningzf`), it works, except that css which points to the wrong place (server root) fails

## UPDATE

it seems to work again now. not sure why too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you configured your vhosts?